# Android - Show more information on a popup

Tags: android, design-patterns, popupwindow

I'm developing an app that includes reviews of items and due to my design, I want to only show all the reviews in a popup window like in Google Play Store:

[image]

What should I use to create that white panel that appears over the current window and contains the necessary information? This should be simple but I'm a newbie and I can't seem to figure out what this "widget" is. Please help me if you are familiar with this so I can use this cool design pattern. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A better way to do it would be using a [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html). You can display information in the form of a popup and it will have its own lifecycle. That will be much better than displaying an activity like a dialog

Answer (score 1):

It seems you want to display a layout as a popup in another activity.

If you want to do this using an Activity instead of a Dialog, you can do this by setting the activity's theme to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in the manifest - this will make the activity appear like a dialog (floating on top of whatever was underneath it).

Comment: This seems like a nice solution! I'll try this out and report back later. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Ram kiran's answer is a good one and one which I like to give also. But just so you have another option to look at you can consider [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html)

As stated in the docs, it is

> A popup window that can be used to display an arbitrary view. The popup window is a floating container that appears on top of the current activity.

I've used this and it works out nicely in some situations. It really depends on what your exact needs are as to which will work best for you.